# Awaited is for A

Tags: word, pattern

- awaited is for A
- multidimensional is for B
- terrified is for C
- friendship is for D
- hungarian is for E
- visiting is for F
- theatrical is for G
- indivisible is for H
- delicious is for I
- distasteful is for J

What are **footprint**, **criticism** and **maturity** for?

Comment: I might be asking for too much of a hint, but would this pattern still work if the letter and word in each of these were reversed? i.e., "A is for awaited; B is for..." etc.

Comment: It's K, L, and M - obviously because that's how you listed them.

Comment: Well, I summed the words based on `{a=1 ... z=26}` and saw no particular pattern. I also used `mod(x,26)` to no avail. Also didn't get anywhere with the character map. It's tagged "pattern" and not "math" so maybe I'm overthinking it..

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that topspin is for P? And is basins for R?

Comment: I tried treating each word as a binary number based on consonants and vowels but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

footprint is for

> Q

criticism is for

> L

maturity is for

> K

**Explanation**

> The letters of interest in each word are those with a dot or a crossbar. In this set, they would be the letters *i*, *t*, or *f*. Letters with a dot denote a dot (or dit) in Morse code, while letters with a crossbar denote a dash (or dah). Extracting the special letters in the order that they occur in each word and translating them to Morse code gives us the below.
>
>  awaited = dot dash = A
>  multidimensional = dash dot dot dot = B
>  terrified = dash dot dash dot = C
>  friendship = dash dot dot = D
>  hungarian = dot = E
>  visiting = dot dot dash dot = F
>  theatrical = dash dash dot = G
>  indivisible = dot dot dot dot = H
>  delicious = dot dot = I
>  distasteful = dot dash dash dash = J
>  footprint = dash dash dot dash = Q
>  criticism = dot dash dot dot = L
>  maturity = dash dot dash = K

Comment: Nice! Can't believe I didn't get this - I've even seen a Sydney University puzzle with the same concept.